# Sharepoint and Libraries

Tags: security, sharepoint

All, we are working creating a shared secret library in Sharepoint. basically the idea being, a user fills out a "Shared Secret" infopath form (AKA "What is your highschool mascot") and then that form is sent to a secure library that only the helpdesk can read.  Currently it looks like our sharepoint admin  doesn't know how to create a secured library. Has anyone done anything similar in sharepoint? Or does anyone know of some good tutorials for creating something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, under Doc Library Settings-Versioning:
Require Content Approval = Yes
Now every new item is "Draft' until someone approves it

"Who should see draft items..."  Select 'Only users who can approve items'
No one can see anyone elses inputs until it is 'approved'

Answer (score 0):

Basically for the library, the admin will have to go to Settings > Permissions for this document library and manage the permissions there.  It's really not that difficult.

I question why you'd be storing user "password" type stuff here.  Using Infopath seems like a terrible waste of resources for this type of information.

Comment: Well the specific issues seems to be more "how to have them add without reviewing everything else in there" but I think we can create (From other peoples suggestions) specific "Add" permissions. 

IN regards to "Why" we are sharing this with 32 other types of applications that require user authentication before any sort of activity is carried out on their account.

Comment: You can also implement a specific workflow that will alter permissions on items added to the document library if the intent is that they could see their own, but not others.

Comment: Basic list functionality of Lists allows you to specify at creation time that users should only be able to view their own items.  You can then create a group of users who can view all items (your helpdesk staff).  No workflow required.  I agree that Infopath seems overkill, if all the form does is populate this list.  If it does more, fair enough.